# Calling Vps.net api class

Tags: php, api, class

I want to use VPS.NET PHP api but i don't know how use given class.
For example i want to call getDomains function which is in VPSNET class.
Class: http://pastebin.com/wn4UYQB7
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Sorry but no one have time to read 1800 lines of code from paste bin.  Please add required minimal code in the question or you will not get any reply.

Comment: I think there is no need to read all the code. I just want to call a function which is in this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but something like:

```
<?php 
//Include the class into the script
include('VPSNET.class.php');

//Start the class & get instance, pass your username, api key ect
$vpsAPI = VPSNET::getInstance($username, $_auth_api_key);

//Call the getDomains method from the class
$result = $vpsAPI->getDomains();

//Do somthing with the result
print_r($result);
?>
```